# Effect of Shortage of Resources on Buildings and Cities

Tags: civilization-5

I know that having a shortage of resources (such as Iron or Uranium) has an effect on units that require that resource. For example, if you have a Nuclear Submarine and -1 Uranium, that Submarine will have a negative combat modifier.

However, does  a shortage of resources affect buildings that require that resource? For example, each Factory you construct requires 1 Coal. Now, I have no Coal in my territory. I've been trading with other civs and city-states to get Coal to build Factories. If I end one of these trading deals (and result in -X Coal), will my Factories output less Production?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went into one of my late game saves and purposefully sabotaged my coal reserves to see what would happen. Even with -7 coal my cities' production was completely unaffected which would lead me to assume that a resource shortage should not negatively affect your buildings in any way, it's just going to prevent you from building anything else requiring that resource until you find another source(s) to refill your reserves.